# How to put an <p> element directly after an <a> element without placing it on a new line

Tags: html, css, line

When I was working on my site I walked towards a problem. I want to have the <.p> element directly after my <.a> element, so it is not a line under it.

*How it is now:*

```
Login 
\
Register
```

*How I want it:*

```
Login \
Register
```

*You can visit my site if you want to take a look:*

v14rkoende.helenparkhurst.net

**This is my html code:**

```
<div class=logreg>

        <div class=logregb>

            <p class=loginl ><a href=login.html class=loginr>Login</a> /</p>
            <p class=loginl ><a href=register.html class=loginr>Registreer</a></p>

        </div>

    </div>
```

**This is my CSS code:**

```
.loginr {
    font-family: Century Gothic;
    color: white; 
    font-size: 12px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    text-decoration: underline;
}

.loginl {
    font-family: Century Gothic;
    color: white; 
    font-size: 12px;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin: 0px;
}

.logreg {
    margin-left:-20px;
}

.logregb {
    width: 0px;
    margin-left: auto ;
    margin-right: auto ;
    margin-top: -40px;
}
```

Thanks for helping me out

---

**Solution was to make the width bigger so for example:**

```
 .logregb {
    width: 100px;
    margin-left: auto ;
    margin-right: auto ;
    margin-top: -40px;
}
```

Thanks to all people for the fast awnsers!

Comment: you should add and close these " " at classes, links etc

Comment: Then you should use an element that is displayed as `inline` element and not one that is displayed as `block` element. Are change that behavior with css.

Comment: I would recommend using a span instead of a p (paragraph).

Comment: @Akshay you only need quotes around attribute values when there is e.g. a space in the value. Otherwise it is not necessary.

Comment: @t.niese That's not the problem here.

Comment: Why do you use `p` elements if you don’t want things to be rendered as paragraphs?

Comment: @Julia K. Not everyone is so experienced as you are, I'm still in my learning phase

Answer (score 0):

try this **(UNTESTED)**:

```
.loginl a {
 float:left;
}
```

Comment: Think about the reason why it is line breaking. The reason is, that the parent element's width is smaller then the width of the text "login" and so the "/" is automatically in the next line. `{ float: left; }` works but it's better to make the parent wider or prevent from line breaking with `nowrap`.

Answer (score 0):

The width of your parent DOM element is to small. Remove the `.logregb {width: 0px;}` because it results in 2 line breaks.

**Alternatively**

Add `nowrap` to your CSS as following:

```
.loginl {
    [...]
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Here is the JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/j3t47pqg/1/

Comment: That did work! I just had to make the width bigger. Stupid me D: Thanks sir!

Comment: If it works, would you give some points to the correct answer please?

Answer (score -1):

```css
p a {
 display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class=logreg>
    <div class=logregb>
        <p class=loginl >
            <a href=login.html class=loginr>Login</a>
            <a href=register.html class=loginr>Registreer</a>
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is that legal? I've never thought to do that. A paragraph is a block level element so is making it an inline-block legal? I didn't immediately find anything in the spec.

Comment: @Rob Why shall it not be legal to switch a block element to `inline`? It is not the finest art but sometimes it could be usefull.

Comment: @algorhythm Because it's not the finest art. Or, perhaps, the spec says you can't. I haven't found a reason yet.

Comment: @Rob You can, it's possible. You can get a `p` element to do what a `span` element does and vice versa. Sometimes you have autogenerated HTML which you can't change and than go for it like this.

Comment: @algorhythm While you can get it to work, that doesn't mean it's legal. That's what I'm questioning (and still haven't looked into).